# Cloud functions context params return undefined

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using cloud functions to listen on new document created on Firestore.

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
            console.log('params', context.params.userId);
});
```

The logs show ***undefined*** instead of the wildcarded param.

This start happening from 15th dec 2018 at midnight.

Is this a bug related to an update of firestore/cloud functions ?
and how we can bypass this issue?

Comment: We started experiencing this too last night. Possible workaround is to use the ID in the snapshot object, e.g. `const userId = snapshot.id;`

Comment: There is a Github issue for this now: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/357

Comment: Seems this issue has been posted in Firebase's status dashboard. : status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18044

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be a bug in the Firebase Functions SDK or platform currently (15 December 2018).

**Work-around:**

**Update** The proper way to access the parent document ID is through `change.after.ref.parent.parent.id` or `snapshot.ref.parent.parent.id`. Note the **`.parent.parent`**.

If you are expecting parameters with the document IDs, you can probably work around the problem by using the data provided in the first argument to you function.

Here is an example with an `onCreate` triggered function:

```
export const myCreateTriggeredFn = firestore
  .document("user/{userId}/friends/{friendId}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    let { userId, friendId } = context.params;

    if (typeof userId !== "string" || typeof friendId !== "string") {
      console.warn(`Invalid params, expected 'userId' and 'friendId'`, context.params);

      userId = snapshot.ref.parent.parent.id;
      friendId = snapshot.id;
    }

    // Continue your logic here...
  });
```

And for an `onWrite` triggered function:

```
export const myChangeTriggeredFn = firestore
  .document("user/{userId}/friends/{friendId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

    let { userId, friendId } = context.params;

    if (typeof userId !== "string" || typeof friendId !== "string") {
      console.warn(`Invalid params, expected 'userId' and 'friendId'`, context.params);

      userId = change.after.ref.parent.parent.id;
      friendId = change.after.id;
    }

    // Continue your logic here...
  });
```

For the sake of completeness and to highlight the bug, both examples shows how you would normally extract the IDs from the `context.params` and then the added work-around to extract the IDs from the snapshot/change objects.

Comment: Thank you. The workaround seems to be working, but I get a new issue not related to my code:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Firestore.snapshot_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:422:127)
    at beforeSnapshotConstructor (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:140:30)
    at changeConstructor (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:144:49)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.

Comment: I can't even imagine how many production systems have been broken because of this... Did they make any announcement on it?

Comment: @iouhammi we are seeing that error too. Looking into workarounds for that right now.

Comment: @iouhammi I did an update to the examples. `snapshot.ref.parent` is apparently the collection reference. You must use `snapshot.ref.parent.parent` to find the parent document.

Comment: @rmac, thank you for the work-around, it saves me a critical situation on my production server.

Comment: Glad I found that. Everything are broken today on our side because of this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the Google employee working on the incident. There is a known compatibility issue for customers using the SDK when Firestore was in a private alpha and have not upgraded.

Could affected customers who are running their code with an SDK version *newer* than 0.6.2 respond? If you are running version 0.6.1 you can upgrade to 0.6.2 with no code changes to fix.

Comment: Which SDK? The "firebase-functions" NPM package? This is an extract from our package.json:
```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "2.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: the firebase-functions: 2.1.0 is what I was asking about. It seems like firebase-functions may no longer guard against this server change. We are continuing to roll back.

Comment: Ok thanks. FYI, I can see in our yarn.lock that we get "@google-cloud/firestore@^0.19.0" indirectly as well.

Comment: my dependencies: {"firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"}. And in the package-lock.json I can see this dependecy "@google-cloud/firestore": "0.16.1", same version required by firebase-admin.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you also running in node 8 or node 6? For clarity we're already rolling back the change that caused this, though it'll help to diagnose the root cause so we an avoid it happening again.

Comment: I am using Node 8 as well. My app was down for pretty much the entire day yesterday (IST) and I was glued to my laptop trying to manually do everything that cloud function would do until I had to ask my clients to stop using the app for the last few hours. It's a new app and few clients are using us for their daily billing so it's a big issue if the app just stops working.
App is working fine now though. Thanks for the help! Is there any advice on what to do if we face these kind of issues?

Comment: As stated above, the service was rolled back on the 15th. We've identified the root cause and a way to better regression test in controlled environments before rolling forward again. Thank you everyone who contributed to the error reporting, debugging, and workaround process.